# NiFi Doesn't update template information when I update xml

Tags: templates, apache-nifi

I am trying to promote my Nifi Job from Dev to QA and For the I am using template.  I know template doesn't store senstive information (i.e. password and other info) and I am okay with it.

However, even if I change other values in XML and then upload the template it doesn't work.

Do I need to restart the nifi server? or so something else for tempalte to be reflected?

The only thing I want to change in this template is the **Queue Name** and **Host Name**. However if I change it in XML template and upload it it's not working.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<template encoding-version="1.2">
    <description></description>
    <groupId>6893964f-0161-1000-c252-8edd203653e6</groupId>
    <name>template1</name>
    <snippet>
        <processGroups>
            <id>e0bb9818-49e5-3194-0000-000000000000</id>
            <parentGroupId>62dd8ddb-07e2-3459-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId>
            <position>
                <x>0.0</x>
                <y>0.0</y>
            </position>
            <comments></comments>
            <contents>
                <processors>
                    <id>a2cb42ea-5e05-362d-0000-000000000000</id>
                    <parentGroupId>e0bb9818-49e5-3194-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId>
                    <position>
                        <x>414.0</x>
                        <y>174.0</y>
                    </position>
                    <bundle>
                        <artifact>nifi-amqp-nar</artifact>
                        <group>org.apache.nifi</group>
                        <version>1.5.0</version>
                    </bundle>
                    <config>
                        <bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel>
                        <comments></comments>
                        <concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>
                        <descriptors>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Queue</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>Queue</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Host Name</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>Host Name</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Port</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>Port</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Virtual Host</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>Virtual Host</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>User Name</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>User Name</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Password</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>Password</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>AMQP Version</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>AMQP Version</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>ssl-context-service</key>
                                <value>
                                    <identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.ssl.SSLContextService</identifiesControllerService>
                                    <name>ssl-context-service</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>cert-authentication</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>cert-authentication</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>ssl-client-auth</key>
                                <value>
                                    <name>ssl-client-auth</name>
                                </value>
                            </entry>
                        </descriptors>
                        <executionNode>ALL</executionNode>
                        <lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant>
                        <penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration>
                        <properties>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Queue</key>
                                <value>testq</value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Host Name</key>
                                <value>abcd.com</value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Port</key>
                                <value>5672</value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Virtual Host</key>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>User Name</key>
                                <value>gshah</value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>Password</key>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>AMQP Version</key>
                                <value>0.9.1</value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>ssl-context-service</key>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>cert-authentication</key>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>ssl-client-auth</key>
                                <value>REQUIRED</value>
                            </entry>
                        </properties>
                        <runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis>
                        <schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod>
                        <schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy>
                        <yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration>
                    </config>
                    <name>ConsumeAMQP</name>
                    <relationships>
                        <autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate>
                        <name>success</name>
                    </relationships>
                    <state>STOPPED</state>
                    <style/>
                    <type>org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP</type>
                </processors>
            </contents>
            <name>Consumer</name>
            <variables/>
        </processGroups>
    </snippet>
    <timestamp>02/05/2018 23:22:10 EST</timestamp>
</template>
```

Comment: How are you uploading the template? Via the GUI or the Rest API?
I believe it doesn't automatically overwrite old versions of the template, so you have to remove existing ones.
If you can move to NiFi-1.5.0 then you can skip templates entirely and do this via NiFi-Registry and Variable-Registry

Answer (score 0):

You can use  NiFi Registry, it's perfect for what you need.
Also I suggest you to read [this article](https://pierrevillard.com/2018/04/09/automate-workflow-deployment-in-apache-nifi-with-the-nifi-registry/), it's really well explained how you can deploy different environmnets.

> I’ll discuss ways you have to automate deployment and
>   promotion of workflows between multiple environments using the NiFi
>   Registry. I’ll discuss and demonstrate two options you have that you
>   need to know about:
>
> The NiFi CLI released with the NiFi Toolkit 1.6.0
>   The NiPyAPI python library 0.8.0